# how to create a localized sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I have an English version of SharePoint installed. Just for the sake of a direct question, how can I create a German site inside of this English installation?

I know what you might be thinking - install the language packs. Which I have done... both WSS and SharePoint including SP1 and SP2 for both language packs....

What do I need to do now... When I go to create a site collection, it looks exactly the same, no drop down to select a specific language, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the key to this puzzle.

The MSDN documentation tells you to download

WSS Language Pack, SharePoint 2007 Language Pack, then apply SP1 and SP2 to each language pack.

The MSDN documentation is also misleading, dare I say flat out wrong!

What you need to do is login to your MSDN subscription ( if you don't have one - then you might be able to search for the language packs, but I tried and could not find any public link to a language pack other than the english pack).

Once you're logged in - select the language (top right) of the language pack you wish to download ( could be German or Czech or any language that is available in that list).

Once you've selected the context language, now locate SharePoint 2007, under servers in the left.

Magically one of the items in the list of downloads that appear will be the language pack you've been looing for. Download and Install - and the language should now be available under create site collection......